# Call to a member function on a non-object - but the object exists

Tags: php, object

I encounter a serious problem that occurs sometimes. The error-message is 'Fatal error: Call to a member function elapsed() on a non-object in /var/www/quantum-framework-0.9.1-ns-alpha/class/log/LogFacility.class.php on line 40'

Here's the code - line 40 is that $this->timer->elapsed()-thing:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->timer        = new \core\base\Timing();
    print_r($this);
    $this->timer_start  = $this->timer->elapsed();

    [...]
}
```

The output from print_r($this) is:

```
core\log\LogFacility Object
(
    [level:core\log\LogFacility:private] => TRACE
    [file:core\log\LogFacility:private] => 
    [filename:core\log\LogFacility:private] => 
    [enabled:core\log\LogFacility:private] => 
    [timer:core\log\LogFacility:private] => core\base\Timing Object
        (
            [start:core\base\Timing:private] => 1371141304.0793
            [stop:core\base\Timing:private] => 0
            [q:core\base\Quobject:private] => 
            [supported_vars:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [timer_start:core\log\LogFacility:private] => 
    [logs:core\log\LogFacility:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [supported_vars:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => level
            [1] => filename
            [2] => enabled
        )

    [q:core\base\Quobject:private] => core\log\LogFacility
)
```

So, how can that happen? Remember, the error happens only sometimes - mostly when I changed other files that do not have anything to do with this timing-measurement-functionality, in addition (as you can see) the object I created just a line above exists.

Oh, btw the elapsed() method exists and is public.

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Timer is a private variable that you are accessing directly? I would think it should be $this->getTimer()->elapsed()

Comment: Erm why? private class variables (and if it is an object their methods) can be accessed directly.